# Rails Reporting Object - Map to New Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dictionary, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a complex multi-object query that is being used for reporting to customers and isn't dependent on new transactional data. With the volume of data I'm dealing with, it seems more efficient to use a custom query instead of loading all of my models up (which I was originally doing and even with effective filtering, it was getting slow).

I've gone as far as creating a class to represent my report (combining attributes from several models), but I'm stuck on something that seems fairly easy now.

I have a new class named **AttendeeReport**

It has the following attributes:

```
 attendee_id, first_name, last_name, email_address, rsvp_id, response_id, etc
```

This is used for reporting (in jquery datatables, and possibly elsewhere) and I'm using this query to pull from multiple models correctly into an array of my correct attributes:

```
list =  Attendee.joins(:event).joins(:focus_group_prospect).joins(:post_focus_group_survey).joins(:lead).joins(:vendor).where("events.focus_group_client_id = ?", client_id).select("attendees.id as attendee_id, leads.first_name, etc").all
```

How would map that result to a new array of AttendeeReport without using each field in the array? Is there a merge or map feature that I'm not familiar with that does this dynamically?

Note: I've dramatically decreased the number of attributes shown since they don't matter.

### Update: Reflection?

Thinking on this if there isn't an easy way to do this via a map or merge, wondering if a reflection approach would work too (iterate over all attributes and match them up).

Comment: It looks like a list of Attendees.  Some places to start - Presenters are good for this sort of thing (or View Model, which I think is a better term.)  You might also look at this blog post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/.  It'll give you some more ideas on related topics.  For example - you might want to split up the querying and the reporting.  Storing the results temporarily somewhere else (in Redis?)

Comment: Thanks @Swards I will probably update the question a bit. I've ended up using a ActiveModel to bind my report to something not stored in the database. But I'm thinking of retrieving it into a more permanent flat solution for just reporting (away from the transaction model). I'll take a look at presenters and read that link. Thanks.